# For Azure Time trigger function. Is it compulsory to add Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions or not. if yes why?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I am new to azure functions. To Create azure function, Is it compulsory to add `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions` or not.

If yes, why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timer extension is in [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions assembly](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/dev/src/WebJobs.Extensions/Extensions/Timers/TimerTriggerAttribute.cs#L6) so it's necessary for our project references.

To be more accurate, `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions` is necessary to build and run Azure Function whatever language and trigger we want to use. This is all by design.

But we don't need to worry either have control over these built-in parts at all. When we create a c# Azure Function locally, it references `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` by default, which includes `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs`, `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions` and so on to make functions work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. As taken from [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to#binding-types):

> **Binding types**
>
> The following trigger and binding types are included in the Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs package:
>
> - Blob storage
> - Queue storage
> - Table storage
>
> To use other trigger and binding types, install the NuGet package that contains them and call a Use method on the JobHostConfiguration object. For example, **if you want to use a Timer trigger, install Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions** and call UseTimers in the Main method, as in this example: …

Now, for the why: I do not know why they decided to put this in a separate package. Fact is, for timer triggers the classes etc. needed are in that package.